# json.loads throwing error when trying to convert an array of JSON into Python list

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am using Django Rest Framework 2.4, and inside a serializer I have this piece of code

```
def validate_fields(self, attrs, source):                                                                                               
    print(attrs)                                                                                                                        
    fields = json.loads(attrs[source])
```

I keep getting the error saying: No JSON object could be decoded. `validate_fields` gets called but gets `fields` as a string instead of a Python List of Strings.

I'm current getting

```
{"fields": '["a", "b", "c"]'}
```

When I want to be receiving this, which is what I'm sending

```
{"fields": ["a", "b", "c"]}
```

[image]

Comment: What is the content of *attrs[source]*? Could you check it?

Comment: Why do you want to sue them? ;-)

Comment: IIRC in `validate_fields` there's no need to call `json.loads` just calling `attrs[source]` should return the list. Also make sure you've set the `Content-type` header as `application/json` when sending the request.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary I have done all that. read the answer by Kevin and my comment on it.

Comment: @maccinza: The whole array is coming as string in the output of attrs[source]. That is why I am using json.loads to convert it to a python list of strings. DOn't go on the numbers in string, it could really be anything in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Django REST Framework handles the JSON decoding for you.

Your output for `attrs` makes sense: it's a Python dictionary containing a Python list with string values. There is no need to further decode this, as Django REST Framework has already done that for you while taking in the request.

You can use the value of `attrs[source]` now, it's in the format you were expecting. You may have been expecting a list of integers (not stringified integers), in which case you can post-process the list and map it with `int`. If it wasn't, the output for `attrs` would be along the lines of the following:

```
{"fields": '["1", "2", "3"]'}
```

*Note the new quotes.* This would mean that Django REST Framework was not able to read in the JSON data, so it gave it to you as a string. This could also mean that it didn't know to read it as a list, in which case read on to find the second possible solution.

---

Also make sure the `fields` field on your serializer is set to `many=True` or is wrapped [in a `ListField`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#listfield).

```
class ExampleSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    fields = serializers.ListField(child=serializers.CharField())
```

That could explain why the Python list is getting coerced into a string, which would explain why it can't be parsed, as Python lists don't perfectly match up with JSON lists.

Comment: Yes exactly. output of attrs is indeed {"fields": '["1", "2", "3"]'}.
The whole array is a string, that's why I am using json.loads to convert it to a python list of strings. That is when I am ge  tting the error. Don't go on the numbers, it could be any string.

Comment: Are you sending it as a string of JSON? DRF should interpret it if you're just including it (without being a string).

Comment: Yes. I am sending it as a valid JSON string. I even tried it on JSONLint.

Comment: I just updated this with the possible issue. Are you not wrapping the serializer field in a ListField? If you aren't doing that, it would explain why the `CharField` is converting the list to a string.